# Why does an externally updated array not automatically refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class

I have a js class that handles some logic, and trying to use it in angular so it can automatically update when the value changes does not work, only when I use angular functions works , the reference is ok, but I sure need something else to tell angular that I need it to listen when the array changes externally.
THANKS!

http://jsfiddle.net/9k2zw1ar/

```
//create class exposed to window
(function(w){

    var Foo=function(){
        this.add=function(){
            Foo.arr.push('js-'+(Math.random() * 100));
        }
    }
    Foo.arr=['a','b','c'];
    w.Foo=Foo;
})(window);
//instantiate one class , used in button
var foo=new Foo;
//angular app
var App= angular.module('App',[]);
//add array reference using "Value" 
App.value('arr',Foo.arr);
//angular controller
App.controller('ClientController', ['$scope','arr', function($scope,arr) {
  $scope.markers = arr;
  $scope.add=function(){
    arr.push('ng-'+(Math.random() * 100));
  };
}]);
```

here is the html code

```
<div ng-app="App" >

<div ng-controller="ClientController">

  <div  ng-repeat='marker in markers'>
              <p> {{marker}}</p>

  </div>
    <button ng-click='add()'>add NG</button>
    <button  onclick="foo.add()">add js</button>
</div>

</div>
```

**PROBLEM:**
When I change the array with the button "add JS" it does not update automatically. but when I press the "add ng" button the array is shown and updated right away.

Comment: The reason that this is happening is that angular triggers digest cycles when data is change withing its own scope, However if the data is changed externally then angular does not see/know about a change and thus can not evaluate changes. Please read about [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) for a better understanding.

Comment: I must say that your problem is not the updates but the way you are trying to code this. Once you go Angular, you must stay Angular as much as possible. If you keep coding in a way that makes you define global objects and stick them in Angular, you will keep having problems. This isn't something you should be doing.

Comment: @AlicanC This problem OP is describing doesn't mean that he actually writes apps like this. There can be multiple cases when you need to be able to hook into existent angular application. And it doesn't mean any bad practice. For example debugging, profiling code which needs to works with Angular app. So one simple must be aware of the principles of how angular works, and how outside world can interact with angular app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you change array from outside of the angular app, it doesn't know that something has changed. Normally you need to notify it, so the scope needs to update its watchers. All you need to do is to trigger digest loop manually, for example by calling `$apply` method on the root scope.

The only tricky part is that you need to access the scope somehow from outside. To access the root scope of the application you need to call `scope` method of the `angular.element(appRoot)` element. Where `appRoot` is a DOM element on which application is registered (`ng-app` attribute). For example something like this:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.add = function () {
        Foo.arr.push('js-' + (Math.random() * 100));
        this.apply();
    };

    this.apply = function() {
        var appRoot = document.querySelector('[ng-app]');
        angular.element(appRoot).scope().$apply();
    };
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9k2zw1ar/1/

Answer (score 1):

As @dfsq point out, using `$apply` works.

Or instead of using `onclick` you can use the angular version [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).  `ng-click` automatically handles triggering a digest cycle (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29).

```
<button ng-click="foo.add()">add js</button>
```

For this to work foo needs to be visible on your scope.  Adding this to your controller will accomplish that:

```
$scope.foo = foo;
```

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/kmmuao7u/

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing setup without any substantial refactor it also works this way...

Change this

```
<button  onclick="foo.add()">add js</button>
```

To this

```
<button  ng-click='addJs()'>add js</button>
```

**Note:** change 'addJs' to the name of your liking

Add this line to your controller

```
$scope.addJs = foo.add;
```

Angular will update the ng-repeat on the 'arr' array all by itself as it is already attached to scope via $scope.markers.

Here is the working fiddle for THIS example...

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/uqypmwc4/)